# LDAP: error code 49 - cannot bind the principalDn

Tags: ldap, oracle-aq, apacheds, ldapconnection

I'm a newbie to ApacheDS.I just created a new partition in ApcheDS. When i try to register my connection factory i get above error..(with OracleAQ )

My code is;

```
    // ldap settings
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, AQjmsConstants.INIT_CTX_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389/");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system,dc=acme,dc=com"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
```

My LDIF file looks like;

```
dn: dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: organization
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: top
dc: acme
o: Acme,Inc

dn: cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: orclContext
objectClass: top
cn: OracleContext

dn: cn=db1,cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: orclContext
objectClass: top
cn: db1

dn: cn=OracleDBConnections,cn=db1,cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: orclContext
objectClass: top
cn: OracleDBConnections

dn: cn=OracleDBQueue,cn=db1,cn=OracleContext,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: orclContext
objectClass: top
cn: OracleDBQueue
```

What is the wrong with my connection parameters? any help would be appreciate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was, i haven't created a user entry for that particular new partition..I solved it now..

Comment: do you have any sample document on this?
oracleaq or spring-ldap?

Answer (score 5):

Change the bind DN to uid=admin,ou=system instead of uid=admin,ou=system,dc=acme,dc=com (this DN is invalid as per your current server data)

Comment: If i did like that,im getting;                                    LDAP: error code 34 - Invalid root DN given :  cn=oracledbconnections,null                                           So, that i created above partition ( cn=OracleDBConnections)